# Get Data from multiple Input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, input

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript"   
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#num").click(function () {
         $(".Box:first").clone().appendTo("#form");
       });
   });
 </script>
 </head>
   <body>
 <div id="form">
 Hai Add Another by clicking the button
 </div>
 <div class='Box'>
 <input id ="j" type="text" />
<input id ="Text1" type="text" />
   </div>
  <button id="num">Click Me</button>
  <button id="BtnSave">Save</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When i Click on Click me button it works.That is to add another set of textboxes. Here  My problem is i need the data from these input textbox's.And the number of textbox's can be 5 to 10 based on the user clicking on Click Me button.It would be great if it is VBS.I need the data a user enters in the inputbox, when the user clicks on the save button.It can like a string.I just need the data.

Comment: Please remove the misleading VBScript tag.

Comment: Need the data where? As part of your form submit? In the browser to perform a calculation? Be specific.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear...
Could you please reformulate your question, and add details about what you would like, what is happening now, and what is wrong about it... Thanks

Comment: I am able to append new textboxes by clicking on the button.but,I need to get the data from the multiple textboxes..

Comment: I'd expect to see 2 things in this question. 1) What the HTML looks like after `#num` is clicked, and 2) what you've tried to accomplish your goal.